# Add line break after every line

Tags: line-breaking

When I enter this

```
C = B log(1+SNR)
270.88 = 200 log(1+SNR)
```

The two lines are printed on the same line. I can force a line break by using `\\` but this is very annoying. Is there a way to automatically force a line break after every newline in the source?

Comment: Is this material to be typeset as code (a listing) or as an equation (possibly with alignment)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe you want the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package? If you are using LaTeX, that is.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I might add that another option is the verbatim environment (no package needed).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\obeylines`. In this way every line break in the source is a line break in the output. If you need this behavior locally, encase it in braces, like `{\obeylines...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
Some text
Some text in a new line
\end{document}
```

[image]